# Value of input box is resetting after 4 numbers

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code. I am trying to dynamically update the input field with the formatted number.

```js
$("#money").keyup(function() {
    var x = this.value;
    var y = parseInt(x).toLocaleString();
    this.value = y;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id='money' />
```

Thank you!

EDIT: Changed to type="text" still same outcome. I do need to have the format included. When i use the console to see the output it works as intended.

Comment: Use input type text then. You cannot have non-numeric content in input type number. Entering non-numeric content, be it manually or programmatically, will result in the value being nulled.

Comment: `toLocalString()` adds comma separators, which aren't valid.

Comment: @connexo i did try that, still same result

Comment: Please don't post links to your code on 3rd party sites. Those links can die over time. Just insert a "Code Snippet" (as I've done for you) into your question.

Comment: @ScottMarcus i appreciate that, i am sorry.

Comment: @Barmar that is what i need thou, 12555 i want it to show 12,555

Comment: @Almoe10 Then you can't use `type="number"`, because that doesn't allow extra characters like that.

Comment: @Barmar i did change it, however same result

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `type="number"` if you want to show numbers with commas, it only allows plain numbers. So use `type="text"`.

But if the number has commas, `parseInt()` won't be able to parse it. Remove all the non-digit characters from the input before parsing it.

```js
$("#money").keyup(function() {
 var x = $(this).val().replace(/\D/g, '');
 var y = parseInt(x).toLocaleString();
  $(this).val(y);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id='money' />
```

Comment: Other languages use different formatting notation. In Germany 10000 is 10.000.

Comment: I've changed it to remove all non-digits.

Comment: @connexo Can you suggest a solution that handles all the different locales?

Comment: Just showing you that's it's not as trivial as your post suggests. There is a reason i18n libraries like Globalize.js are hugely complex.

Comment: i know for locales you can pass parameters toLocalString([locales [, options]]).

Comment: @Almoe10 How would that help? The issue is with parsing the input consistently with how `toLocaleString()` outputs it.

Comment: @Barmar i was thinking that having what you did before was okay, removing the commas and then it formats after to take care of the locale part.

Comment: @Almoe10 As mentioned in a comment, it depends on your locale. If you're in a country that swaps the uses of `.` and `,`, you need to remove `.`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `toLocaleString`, are you trying to achieve some formatted output like 123,34?

> If yes, then when you got your formatted output and do next `keyup`, `parseInt` will again try to parse number and you will get `NaN`. So your `textbox` goes blank.

You are already using jquery, why not do following:

```
$("#money").keyup(function() {
    var x = $(this).val();

    var y = parseInt(x);
  $(this).val(y);

});
```

I also tried `var y = x.toLocaleString();` instead of `parseInt`, textbox doesnt become blank after 4 inputs.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to get it formatted and Barmar did point out the issue with parsing (i was looking at the console log and i didn't get an exceptions).

Comment: If you add alerts on x and y values in your jsfiddle you will see NaN in alerts

Comment: i know that, when it was empty too it would spit out nan

Answer (score -1):

`input type=number` disallows non-numeric characters in the first place, but you can use a text field.

Now, as the format kicks in, your value is lost because `parseInt` will stop parsing as soon as it encounters a non-numeric character. To get around this you can strip out the formatting before calling `parseInt()`.

Also, in the event handler, you have access to the field via the `this` keyword. There is no need for those other variables you set up.

```js
$("#money").on("input", function() {
  // Get rid of the commas, extract the number and format
  this.value = parseInt(this.value.replace(/,/g, ""), 10).toLocaleString('en-us');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id='money'> (hit TAB after entering number)
```

Comment: Funy to attach the event listener using jQuery, and inside it selecting the exact same element that is in `this` using `document.getElementById`. And even doing that twice.

Comment: It doesn't show only 4 numbers, it adds commas after every 3 digits.

Comment: @connexo i am learning javascript, i updated the code so thank you for your input :)

Comment: Actually this completely ignores what OP wants to achieve, which is locale formatting a number while it is being entered.

Comment: Why are you suggesting using `blur` event?

Comment: @connexo Because the underlying problem is that the formatting is being applied while the user is still entering the number and once they get to a 5th digit, the value is replaced with the prior formatted value. Waiting until the user leaves the field allows for more than just a number in the single digit thousands because the value is only replaced once. If you run my snippet, that really only differs by the event, the code works.

Comment: What if I enter a number, blur, then come back to edit?

Comment: You can make it readonly when blurring. Why not require people to concentrate while entering their shit ;)

Comment: @connexo Problem solved and event changed back to `input`.